# `append` complexity

Tags: go

What is the computational complexity of this loop in the Go programming language?

```
var a []int
for i := 0 ; i < n ; i++ {
  a = append(a, i)
}
```

Does `append` operate in linear time (reallocating memory and copying everything on each append), or in amortized constant time (like the way vector classes in many languages are implemnted)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec) says that the `append` built-in function reallocates if necessary.

> [Appending to and copying slices](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices)
>
> If the capacity of s is not large enough to fit the additional values,
>   append allocates a new, sufficiently large slice that fits both the
>   existing slice elements and the additional values. Thus, the returned
>   slice may refer to a different underlying array.

The precise algorithm to grow the target slice, when necessary, for an append is implementation dependent. For the current `gc` compiler algorithm, see the `growslice` function in the Go `runtime` package [`slice.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/slice.go) source file. It's amortized constant time.

In part, the amount-to-grow slice computation reads:

```
    newcap := old.cap
    doublecap := newcap + newcap
    if cap > doublecap {
        newcap = cap
    } else {
        if old.len < 1024 {
            newcap = doublecap
        } else {
            for newcap < cap {
                newcap += newcap / 4
            }
        }
}
```

ADDENDUM

The [Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec) allows implementors of the language to implement the `append` built-in function in a number of ways.

For example, new allocations only have to be "sufficiently large". The amount allocated may be parsimonius, allocating the minimum necessary amount, or generous, allocating more than the minimum necessary amount to minimize the cost of resizing many times. The Go `gc` compiler uses a generous dynamic array amortized constant time algorithm.

The following code illustrates two legal implementations of the `append` built-in function. The generous constant function implements the same amortized constant time algorithm as the Go `gc` compiler. The parsimonius variable function, once the initial allocation is filled, reallocates and copies everything every time. The Go `append` function and the Go `gccgo` compiler are used as controls.

```
package main

import "fmt"

// Generous reallocation
func constant(s []int, x ...int) []int {
    if len(s)+len(x) > cap(s) {
        newcap := len(s) + len(x)
        m := cap(s)
        if m+m < newcap {
            m = newcap
        } else {
            for {
                if len(s) < 1024 {
                    m += m
                } else {
                    m += m / 4
                }
                if !(m < newcap) {
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        tmp := make([]int, len(s), m)
        copy(tmp, s)
        s = tmp
    }
    if len(s)+len(x) > cap(s) {
        panic("unreachable")
    }
    return append(s, x...)
}

// Parsimonious reallocation
func variable(s []int, x ...int) []int {
    if len(s)+len(x) > cap(s) {
        tmp := make([]int, len(s), len(s)+len(x))
        copy(tmp, s)
        s = tmp
    }
    if len(s)+len(x) > cap(s) {
        panic("unreachable")
    }
    return append(s, x...)
}

func main() {
    s := []int{0, 1, 2}
    x := []int{3, 4}
    fmt.Println("data    ", len(s), cap(s), s, len(x), cap(x), x)
    a, c, v := s, s, s
    for i := 0; i < 4096; i++ {
        a = append(a, x...)
        c = constant(c, x...)
        v = variable(v, x...)
    }
    fmt.Println("append  ", len(a), cap(a), len(x))
    fmt.Println("constant", len(c), cap(c), len(x))
    fmt.Println("variable", len(v), cap(v), len(x))
}
```

Output:

gc:

```
data     3 3 [0 1 2] 2 2 [3 4]
append   8195 9152 2
constant 8195 9152 2
variable 8195 8195 2
```

gccgo:

```
data     3 3 [0 1 2] 2 2 [3 4]
append   8195 9152 2
constant 8195 9152 2
variable 8195 8195 2
```

To summarize, depending on the implementation, once the initial capacity is filled, the `append` built-in function may or may not reallocate on every call.

References:

[Dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array)

[Amortized analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis)

> [Appending to and copying slices](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices)
>
> If the capacity of s is not large enough to fit the additional values,
>   `append` allocates a new, sufficiently large slice that fits both the
>   existing slice elements and the additional values. Thus, the returned
>   slice may refer to a different underlying array.
>
> [Append to a slice specification discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/o5rFNqd0VjA/discussion)
>
> The spec (at tip and 1.0.3) states:
>
> "If the capacity of s is not large enough to fit the additional
>   values, `append` allocates a new, sufficiently large slice that fits
>   both the existing slice elements and the additional values. Thus, the
>   returned slice may refer to a different underlying array."
>
> Should this be an "If and only if"? For example, if I know the
>   capacity of my slice is sufficiently long, am I assured that I will
>   not change the underlying array?
>
> [Rob Pike](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/o5rFNqd0VjA/HzJHwgl1y6MJ)
>
> Yes you are so assured.

runtime [slice.go](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/master/src/runtime/slice.go) source file

[Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](http://blog.golang.org/slices)

Comment: Yeah, though it would be nice for the language or library reference to specify the complexity of this though, so users can rely on the complexity when writing large applications.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't reallocate on every append and it is quite explicitly stated in the [docs](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices):

> If the capacity of s is not large enough to fit the additional values, append allocates a new, sufficiently large slice that fits both the existing slice elements and the additional values. Thus, the returned slice may refer to a different underlying array.

Amortized constant time is thus the complexity asked about.

Comment: That doesn't say that "It doesn't reallocate on every append." It just says that it reallocates if necessary.

Comment: @peterSO: Rob Pike, one of the language authors, begs to differ:  https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/o5rFNqd0VjA/HzJHwgl1y6MJ

Comment: No, he doesn't. I've added an addendum to my answer.

Comment: @peterSO: Which of the words in _"Yes you are so assured."_ is not clearly communicating what's the Rob' answer to the [mailing list] OP question? (which was: _"For example, if I know the capacity of my slice is sufficiently long, am I assured that I will not change the underlying array?"_) ;-)

Comment: @zzzz, that *only* is talking about the case where the existing slice is more than large enough. Rob (in that quote) says **exactly nothing** about how much space might be allocated when that is not so. *If* it was only just as much as needed then reallocation would not be amortized.