# where is the elements of slice will store if its size exceed the size of array?

Tags: go

I create a slice from the array OrgArray as follows

```
orgArray:=[3] string{"00","01","02"}
s := orgArray[:2]
s = append(s,"03")
s = append(s,"04")
```

Where 's' is my slice I built up on the array 'orgArray'

If I print the size of the s and orgArray

```
fmt.Println(s) //[00 01 03 04]
fmt.Println(len(s),cap(s)) //4 6
fmt.Println(len(orgArray),cap(orgArray)) //3 3
```

len(s) is 4 but len(orgArray) is only 3 why?

Where is the extra elements of slice is storing while appending?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Appending to and copying slices](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices)
>
> If the capacity of s is not large enough to fit the additional values,
>   append allocates a new, sufficiently large underlying array that fits
>   both the existing slice elements and the additional values. Otherwise,
>   append re-uses the underlying array.

For additional details on how the `append` built-in function works, read this blog post:

[Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](http://blog.golang.org/slices)

Also, see this StackOverflow answer, which illustrates the reallocation capacity calculation:

[`append` complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702419/append-complexity/15703422#15703422)

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    orgArray := [3]string{"00", "01", "02"}
    fmt.Println("orgArray:", &orgArray[0], len(orgArray), orgArray)
    s := orgArray[:2]
    fmt.Println("       s:", &s[0], len(s), cap(s), s)
    s = append(s, "03")
    fmt.Println("       s:", &s[0], len(s), cap(s), s)
    s = append(s, "04")
    fmt.Println("       s:", &s[0], len(s), cap(s), s)
    fmt.Println("orgArray:", &orgArray[0], len(orgArray), orgArray)
}
```

Output:

```
orgArray: 0x1052f2c0 3 [00 01 02]
       s: 0x1052f2c0 2 3 [00 01]
       s: 0x1052f2c0 3 3 [00 01 03]
       s: 0x1051a120 4 6 [00 01 03 04]
orgArray: 0x1052f2c0 3 [00 01 03]
```

Answer (score 2):

slice's struct is like this:

```
struct Slice
{ // must not move anything
 byte* array; // actual data
 uintgo len; // number of elements
 uintgo cap; // allocated number of elements
};
```

while in your example. explain as follow:

```
orgArray := [3]string{"00", "01", "02"}
s := orgArray[:2]
fmt.Println(len(s),cap(s))  //2,3 s is pointer to orgArray
s = append(s, "03")
fmt.Println(len(s),cap(s))  //3,3 cap is enough. s is pointer to orgArray
s = append(s, "04")
fmt.Println(len(s),cap(s))  //4,6 cap is not enough. regenerate array. then s point to the new array.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s := orgArray[:2]
```

Since you take two elements from the original slice and then append two more the length becomes 4. You can see the four elements here:

```
fmt.Println(s) //[00 01 03 04]
```

If you wonder why the capacity is 6 it's because capacity is increased in power of 2. So if you have a slice with capacity 4 and append 5 elements the capacity will become 8. It is related to trying to re-allocate the memory for the slice that often when append occurs.

Comment: But the underlying array orgArray have size only 3.
I built the slice 's' upon the array orgArray.

Comment: A slice is not an array - a slice is dynamic in size, so it will automatically grow when appending objects. Very similar to a List<T> in C#.

Comment: @AlexMathew: `orgArray` is not large enough, so a new underlying array is allocated for `s`. See my answer for details.