# Vector performance in Go and C++

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, vector, go

Please consider these two snippets in GO and C++11. In C++ `std::vector` is a doubling-array which has amortized O(1) insert operation. How to achieve the same performance in GO? Problem is that this GO code is about 3 times slower on my hardware. Run many times.

Compiled:

- `go build vec.go` (go version go1.2.1 linux/amd64)
- `g++ -O2 -std=gnu++11 -o vec vec.cc` (g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2)

**GO version (vec.go):**

```
package main

type X struct {
    x int32
    y float64
}

const N int = 80000000

func main() {
    x := X{123, 2.64}
    s := make([]X, 1)
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        s = append(s, x)
    }
}
```

**C++11 version (vec.cc):**

```cpp
#include <vector>

const int N = 80000000;

struct X {
        int x;
        double y;
};

int main(void)
{
        X x{123, 2.64};
        std::vector<X> s(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
                s.push_back(x);
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't know Go, but if you care about performance, your C++ code should call `reserve` before the loop.

Comment: @jalf No, I'd like the benchmark to be with the same initial array of size 1. C++ version is pretty fast. But Go is perhaps not using the doubling-array algorithm.

Comment: Sure, but comparing inefficient code to inefficient code tells you nothing *useful*. It's like compiling without optimizations enabled. If you want to compare which is faster, both variants should be written to be fast.

Comment: @jalf Changing the reserved size does not change anything. What's inefficient in your opinion?

Comment: Reserving the size up front *should* change the performance. It avoids reallocating memory and copying objects. It's the difference between amortized O(1) and *actual* O(1) complexity.

Comment: @jalf No, you're wrong. Reserving space before hand changes only additive constants.

Comment: @jalf: Well, here you're measuring the amortised cost of the `push_back` operations.  So no, that's not what the difference is.  The difference, if any is observable, only has to do with the memory allocations, and asymptotic analysis is not fine enough to notice that.

Comment: @tmyklebu I agree totally! But I wonder what algorithm is behind `append`. Because it seems that it's not the doubling-array algorithm.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go's specification doesn't require any particular complexity for `append()`, but in practice it's also implemented in ammortized constant time, as described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702419/append-complexity).

The current implementation works as follows: for array sizes below 1024, it doubles as needed, and above 1024 it increases to 1.25x the original size. Increasing by 1.25x is still amortized constant time, but it has the effect of imposing a higher amortized constant factor than an implementation that always doubles. However 1.25x  wastes less memory overall.

If you're getting different performance behavior by only a few times (even at very large N), then you're seeing different constant factors in play. I've noted myself that the machine code produced by the `gc` compiler is much more efficient than that generated by `gccgo`.

To verify for yourself that Go is operating in ammortized constant time, try plotting the time it takes to run your algorithm for several different values of N.

Comment: Finally! Great answer. It seems that most `std::vector` implementations double every time so the `1.25x` factor argument seems perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @eeq: Most `vector` implementations (that I've looked at, anyway) use a fixed factor, but all I've looked at recently used 1.5x instead of doubling.

Comment: "wastes less memory" - more specifically - on modern OSes / commodity desktop/server hardware it wastes less *virtual address space*, which is pretty much free to allocate for the first time in a 64 bit program but a potential issue for 32 bit ones.  Even for 64 bit apps, it could still be an issue when the virtual address space is already backed by RAM as a side effect of earlier dynamic memory usage - trailing capacity beyond peak `size()` may end up pushed to swap even though the current dynamic memory request hasn't touched it.

Comment: @TonyD some operating systems (like Linux) don't overcommit memory by default. Wasting virtual address space may or may not a problem.

Comment: @FUZxxl: doesn't Linux use [heuristic overcommit handling](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting) by default?  Anyway "may or may not be a problem" is all I'm trying to highlight above, with a little justification/insight to back it.

Comment: @TonyD That must be new. Still, this heuristic overcommitting will not let me request a terabyte of address space.

Comment: @FUZxxl: the question's about the difference between resizes by doubling versus 1.25x - to request a terabyte you'd have to have a 512GB vector already.  Well before you get anywhere near that you can expect - on the systems I describe above - to transition through some range of memory usage where the distinction between wasting plentiful virtual address space vs. relatively limited physical memory is meaningful.

Comment: @FUZxxl, @TonyD: Linux has supported overcommitting for a very long time. It's had controls to turn it off since 2.1.27, however overcommit is the default. There are files in /proc to disable or limit overcommit systemwide, and there's `ulimit` to limit things on a process by process basis.

Comment: Interesting point about overcommit. I've been trained to think of wasting virtual address space as eating actual machine resources, but I see that it's more complicated than that.

Comment: @KenBloom Except that ulimit is somewhat broken now that most programs allocate memory with mmap(). If you map a file into memory with write-back semantics, it shouldn't count towards the address space limit, yet it does. This makes mmap-ing huge files tricky if you want to control resource usage at the same time.

Comment: @FUZxxl: is that an unavoidable problem? Or is there a (potentially large) class of applications where that's not a problem?

Comment: @KenBloom It just seriously inhibits the way you can do file IO. IO via mmap() can be so much faster than multiple read() and write() calls. If address space for memory-mapped file counts towards your memory usage, that isn't particularly great.

Answer (score 1):

I've already answered your computational complexity question: [append complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702419/append-complexity). It is amortized constant time.

My results from your benchmark.

```
$ rm vec
$ cat vec.cc
#include <vector>

const int N = 80000000;

struct X {
        int x;
        double y;
};

int main(void)
{
        X x{123, 2.64};
        std::vector<X> s(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
                s.push_back(x);
        }
}
$ g++ -O2 -std=gnu++11 -o vec vec.cc
$ time ./vec
real    0m1.360s
user    0m0.536s
sys 0m0.816s
$ rm vec
$ cat vec.go
package main

type X struct {
    x int32
    y float64
}

const N int = 80000000

func main() {
    x := X{123, 2.64}
    s := make([]X, 1)
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        s = append(s, x)
    }
}
$ go version
go version devel +6b696a34e0af Sun Aug 03 15:14:59 2014 -0700 linux/amd64
$ go build vec.go
$ time ./vec
real    0m2.590s
user    0m1.192s
sys 0m1.388s
$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of elements before hand, you can preallocate it with:

```
s := make([]X, 0, N)
for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
    s = append(s, x)
}
```

Also use Go 1.3, the compiler got some optimizations.

And for better vectorization, try `gccgo`

Comment: Thx, but no, `N` is only for testing purposes. Let's assume the general setting where you only append and append and don't know how long it will last.

Comment: Did you try go1.3 and gccgo?

Comment: Yes, `go1.3` about the same speed, `gccgo-4.9` another 3 times slower!

Comment: I'm just curious, what flags did you use with gccgo? If you used any.