# go benchmark and gc: B/op alloc/op

Tags: testing, memory, go, garbage-collection, benchmarking

benchmark code:

```
func BenchmarkSth(b *testing.B) {
    var x []int
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        x = append(x, i)
    }
}
```

result:

```
BenchmarkSth-4    50000000    20.7 ns/op    40 B/op    0 allocs/op
```

question/s:

- where did 40 B/op come from? (any way of tracing + instructions is greatly appreciated)
- how is it possible to have 40 B/op while having 0 allocs?
- which one affects GC and how? (B/op or allocs/op)
- is it really possible to have 0 B/op using append?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Appending to and copying slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices)
>
> The variadic function append appends zero or more values x to s of
>   type S, which must be a slice type, and returns the resulting slice,
>   also of type S.
>
> ```
> append(s S, x ...T) S  // T is the element type of S
> ```
>
> If the capacity of s is not large enough to fit the additional values,
>   append allocates a new, sufficiently large underlying array that fits
>   both the existing slice elements and the additional values. Otherwise,
>   append re-uses the underlying array.

For your example, on average, [40, 41) bytes per operation are allocated to increase the capacity of the slice when necessary. The capacity is increased using an amortized constant time algorithm: up to len 1024 increase to 2 times cap then increase to 1.25 times cap. On average, there are [0, 1) allocations per operation.

For example,

```
func BenchmarkMem(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    var x []int64
    var a, ac int64
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        c := cap(x)
        x = append(x, int64(i))
        if cap(x) != c {
            a++
            ac += int64(cap(x))
        }
    }
    b.StopTimer()
    sizeInt64 := int64(8)
    B := ac * sizeInt64 // bytes
    b.Log("op", b.N, "B", B, "alloc", a, "lx", len(x), "cx", cap(x))
}
```

Output:

```
BenchmarkMem-4      50000000            26.6 ns/op        40 B/op          0 allocs/op
--- BENCH: BenchmarkMem-4
    bench_test.go:32: op 1 B 8 alloc 1 lx 1 cx 1
    bench_test.go:32: op 100 B 2040 alloc 8 lx 100 cx 128
    bench_test.go:32: op 10000 B 386296 alloc 20 lx 10000 cx 12288
    bench_test.go:32: op 1000000 B 45188344 alloc 40 lx 1000000 cx 1136640
    bench_test.go:32: op 50000000 B 2021098744 alloc 57 lx 50000000 cx 50539520
```

For `op = 50000000`,

```
B/op = floor(2021098744 / 50000000) = floor(40.421974888) = 40

allocs/op = floor(57 / 50000000) = floor(0.00000114) = 0
```

Read:

[Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

[Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](https://blog.golang.org/slices)

['append' complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702419/append-complexity)

To have zero B/op (and zero allocs/op) for append, allocate a slice with sufficient capacity before appending.

For example, with `var x = make([]int64, 0, b.N)`,

```
func BenchmarkZero(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    var x = make([]int64, 0, b.N)
    var a, ac int64
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        c := cap(x)
        x = append(x, int64(i))
        if cap(x) != c {
            a++
            ac += int64(cap(x))
        }
    }
    b.StopTimer()
    sizeInt64 := int64(8)
    B := ac * sizeInt64 // bytes
    b.Log("op", b.N, "B", B, "alloc", a, "lx", len(x), "cx", cap(x))
}
```

Output:

```
BenchmarkZero-4     100000000           11.7 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
--- BENCH: BenchmarkZero-4
    bench_test.go:51: op 1 B 0 alloc 0 lx 1 cx 1
    bench_test.go:51: op 100 B 0 alloc 0 lx 100 cx 100
    bench_test.go:51: op 10000 B 0 alloc 0 lx 10000 cx 10000
    bench_test.go:51: op 1000000 B 0 alloc 0 lx 1000000 cx 1000000
    bench_test.go:51: op 100000000 B 0 alloc 0 lx 100000000 cx 100000000
```

Note the reduction in benchmark CPU time from around 26.6 ns/op to around 11.7 ns/op.

Comment: any ideas on question 3?